# How to parse this HTML text using htmlagilitypack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, innerhtml

So below are the **lines of code**,

```
    <td class="line1left"><a href="scenario_WLM-16-SCENARIOS.html#population_SCN02_MS_AddNotes_CAM">SCN02_MS_AddNotes_CAM</a></td><td class="line1left">798 (6.14%)
    </td><td class="line1left">0.9</td><td class="line1left">0s (<span> - %</span>)
    </td><td class="line1left">0% (<span class="goodPercentage">-100%</span>)
    </td>

    <td class="line1left"><a href="scenario_WLM-16-SCENARIOS.html#population_SCN05_MS_UpdateCustomer_CAM">SCN05_MS_UpdateCustomer_CAM</a></td><td class="line1left">888 (6.83%)
    </td><td class="line1left">1.0</td><td class="line1left">0s (<span> - %</span>)
    </td><td class="line1left">0% (<span class="goodPercentage">-100%</span>)
    </td>
```

From the first block, I need to get `SCN02_MS_AddNotes_CAM` and `798`. To get `798` I am using this code, but I am getting the `(6.14%)` also, which I don't want.

```
    var content1 = doc1.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='line1left']")[1].InnerText;
```

I want to get `798` only. So can anybody help me?

I also want to know how to get the same values from the second block. I was under the impression that the number inside the brackets represents the different occurrences of the class `line1left`. But here it is representing the different `InnerHtml` elements.

```
    [1]
```

Does anybody know how to get this to work?
Thanks a lot in advance.!

Answer (score 0):

```
  var line1left_list = (from d in document.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                                where d.Name == "td " && d.Attributes["class"] != null
                                && (d.Attributes["class"].Value == "line1left")
                                select d);

  foreach (HtmlNode line1left in line1left_list)
  {
        var _link = line1left.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault();

        string linkUrl = "";
        string link = "";

        if (_link != null)
        {
             linkUrl = _link.Attributes["href"].Value;
             link = _link.InnerText


        }
  }
```

Comment: If the "798" always comes after the link, you could try this _link.Descendants() and take the first HtmlNode's inner text.

Comment: The last line "link = _link.InnerText;" always gives me the InnerText value of the last(second) block of line1left. How do i get the value of the first block and all the blocks in between?

Comment: You could create a String array and add all the links to it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the InnerText of all `<td>` tags with the class attribute of "line1left", unless that `<td>` has an `<a>` inside of it, in which case you want the InnerText of `<a>`.

Here is an example that will do just that. If the `<td>` has an `<a>`, then `<a>` is selected, otherwise `<td>` is selected.

```
HtmlDocument doc1 = new HtmlDocument();
doc1.Load("xmlfile2.xml");

var nodes = doc1.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("(//td[@class='line1left']/a) | (//td[@class='line1left' and not(a)])");

foreach(var node in nodes)
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText.Trim());
```

This will select all the nodes in the document. You can use regular C# code to strip off the unwanted formatting on the individual values.